# Gatsby having slow interactive and delay response

Tags: reactjs, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, gatsby, web-testing

I've been looking the answer why website https://7starscustom.id has slow response, 
the pagespeed shows i had 5 secs interactive, but it's really slow when i tried to open for the first time (using private/incgonito) before the website caching. if i start to click everything, it would be delayed and resulting to navigate everywhere when the website finally ready.

can someone help me to debug, the gatsby blog said it might be the 3rd library, but i have still no clue for a week.

the https://web.dev/measure/  and https://gtmetrix.com/. gave me a good score, but im new for debugging this problem, so imnot sure the benchmark of js load / image load or my actual mistake

Comment: Did you figure this out already? I am in a similar situation

Comment: Facing same issue. Please do share here if you were able to solve the problem